# Which GSM for Tyvek for rack rear panel?

Tags: dust

I would like to add a rear wall to my Ikea Ivar rack that is light, easy to attach and keeps dust out. I was thinking of using Tyvek but Tyvek comes in different versions (55, 75, 105 GSM). I understand that Tyvek is a strong, light material.

Comment: What is the goal of the tyvek ? Just to keep dust out the light weight material should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it's just to keep the dust out. I just never handled Tyvek before and was just wondering if the 55 GSM is strong enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the cheapest or lightest weight you can get. For a dust shield it really won’t matter.

I have made funnels out of scraps, I keep some scraps in the farm truck for this reason (if you have scraps they can be handy around a vehicle.

The lighter weights feel softer like the tyvek suits it is still tough I might roll it and staple it on the edge but I staple it on buildings and other than sewing / heat tape haven’t seen it attached other ways.